# Are RxJava2 Observables covariant? or: is it safe to narrow an Observable (upcast its value type)?

Tags: java, rx-java2, upcasting, narrowing

Given a class `Foo` and a class `Bar extends Foo`, it seems as though it should be safe to cast an `Observable<Bar>` to an `Observable<Foo>` — `Observables` are read-only, aren't they? But there doesn't seem to be any out-of-the box way to do it without warnings, other than something like

```
Observable<Bar> barObservable = ...
Observable<Foo> fooObservable = barObservable.map(Foo.class::cast);
// or: Observable<Foo> fooObservable = barObservable.cast(Foo.class);
```

which compiles without errors, but seems as though it will incur extra method call overhead unless the compiler is very clever.

Other libraries like vavr.io have built-in [`narrow()`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Stream.html#narrow-io.vavr.collection.Stream-) methods that at least suppress the warning for you, the equivalent of:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Observable<T> narrow(Observable<? extends T> o) {
  return (Observable<T>) o;
}
```

But RxJava2 doesn't seem to provide such methods, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something and it's not as safe as I think.

---

**ETA:** As (relatively) clean as `map(Foo.class::cast)` / `cast(Foo.class)` looks, I've realized it's preferable to write

```
barObservable.map(b -> (Foo) b);
```

as this will give you a compilation error if `Bar` cannot be cast to `Foo`.

(It won't help with generics, though; you'll just get an unsafe cast warning. For generics, the custom `narrow()` implementation above seems more type-safe.)

Comment: The method you provided is the way to do it. `narrow()` may provide a wrapper around that, with error messages, etc.

Comment: Java's type system does not support such conversion without warning. There is a [proposal](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/300) to support co- and contravariance more directly, but since RxJava is targeting version 6, it can't benefit from such enhancements.

Comment: @akarnokd it's a warning because the programmer knows more than the compiler about whether it's safe, and `@SuppressWarnings` exists for the case where the programmer knows it's safe but the compiler can't tell. vavr.io provides `narrow()` as part of the library because they know it's safe and they want to relieve programmers of the burden of having to suppress their own warnings everywhere. What I'm asking is whether it is in fact safe in the RxJava2 context.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable` has a [cast](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#cast-java.lang.Class-) operator.

Comment: It does, so that's an alternative to `map(Foo.class::cast)`, but it's not type-safe (and is in fact less type-safe than `map(b -> (Foo) b)` -- see my update to the question).